# Can I activate a jQuery script with hashtag in URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a div that drops down and appears using jQuery when a user clicks on a specific link. Would it be possible to activate this script on page load if the URL ends in a certain hashtag?

To be more specific. My site has a panel on every page that contains a form users fill out to request a quote on our products. If a user visits a product page where the URL is http://mysite.com/product/ipod#quote, I'd like for my javascript activated panel to activate on page load.

And to be clear, the hashtag will not be a location on my page.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 (or, at least, the `mysite` specific 'page not found' page) from your link.

Comment: Sorry about that, that was just an example link! If you're interested to see my working site here is the link: http://iavi.com/itemdesc.asp?ic=CPWX4021N. Click on the Quote button to see the javascript I want to activate on page load with a url hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  if(document.location.hash.search('hash') !== -1){
    $('a#with-id').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

`hash` is the name of the hash
`a#with-id` is the selector of the link

if the "hash" is the only value in your hash, you can simply compare with `document.location.hash === '#hash'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Though I can't give a specific answer without knowing a few more details (what hash-tag, what do you mean by a 'hash-tag' and what function name are you calling?), but basically:

```
if (window.location.hash == 'hashtagValue') {
    // do stuff
}
```

For example, assuming that you visited the page at `http://example.com/index.html#dropDown` then:

```
if (window.location.hash == 'dropDown') {
    // do stuff, for example:
    alert("You're one the `dropDown` hash of the page!");
}
```

would show the alert. You could also call a function, or do something else entirely within the `if` condition.
would

Comment: The alert will fire off an error if you don't add a backslash to the apostrophe in "you're".

Comment: Oh, dear lord...now I remember why I started using `"` in alerts...sigh. Thanks, Joey! *Edited* =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my post to be a little more detailed. I was in a rush at the time! =P I tried out your code without changing anything. I navigated to my site with #dropDown at the end of the URL but I didn't get an alert.

Comment: Try to use a simple alert (no `if` or anything *just* the `alert()`): `alert(window.location.hash);` and see what that produces.

Comment: `alert(window.location.hash);` produces an alert with the URL's hashtag. Or an empty alert if there is no hashtag. Unfortunately I still cannot get the `if` statement to work.